# Is it possible to change default Flutter splash screen transition?

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I have a splash screen in my app, made by this [article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen) and it works fine.

I'm wondering is it possible to change a default fade transition between splash screen and the main application?

Answer (score 2):

You should try this plugin:

[customSplash](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_splash)

And there are still more on pub.dev.

The code for custom splash:

```
runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: CustomSplash(
        imagePath: 'assets/flutter_icon.png',
        backGroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        animationEffect: 'zoom-in',
        logoSize: 200,
        home: MyApp(),
        customFunction: duringSplash,
        duration: 2500,
        type: CustomSplashType.StaticDuration,
        outputAndHome: op,
    ),
));
```